# Upgrade Issues - Events links going to home page

Tags: civievent

I have upgraded from version 4.7 to latest version 5.16

When I click on an event live link, even from the admin, i get taken to the home page.  The url is correct xxxx.com//?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=111

I am having other issues, but working on them one by one.

Please helpppppp

Jennifer

Comment: I deactivated all plug ins and it worked, then activated them one by one and found the one having a conflict.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer and accept it? If possible, name the plugin that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Plug In AGP Font Awesome Collection was conflicting with CiviCRM, no idea why, but Disabled it and it is now working great.